# iOS - Core Data deleting object on parent before creating child is ignored by child

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm not sure if this is a Core Data bug or I'm doing something wrong.
I have an object on viewContext. I delete the object on viewContext, then create a child context with viewContext as the parent. Parent indicates that 'someObject.isDeleted` is true (correctly).

Neither the parent nor child are saved yet.

The child context indicates that the object still exists and `isDeleted` is false. (incorrect).

I tested with just updating the object's properties and adding new objects and it works properly, but deleting does not.

What am I doing wrong here?

I understand that changes on a parent are not automatically pushed to child IF the changes occur AFTER creating the child (assuming nothing saved), but shouldn't the child be in the same state as parent when first created?

```
func testDelete(someObject: NSManagedObject) {
    guard let parentContext = someObject.managedObjectContext else { return }
    let objectID = someObject.objectID

    parentContext.performAndWait {
        parentContext.delete(someObject)
        print("Parent isDeleted: \(someObject.isDeleted)")
        // Results: "Parent isDeleted: true"
    }

    let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    childContext.parent = parentContext

    childContext.performAndWait {
        let childObject = childContext.object(with: objectID)
        print("Child isDeleted: \(childObject.isDeleted)")
        // Results: "Parent isDeleted: false"
    }
}
```

Comment: When a new context is created the persistent coordinator creates one from the store (that is saved data) and not some other context. If it would have been possible to do so I believe we would have had an init that took the parent context as an argument, something like `NSManagedObjectContext(parent: parentContext, concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)`

Comment: Yeah I've always thought it odd there wasn't a parent parameter in the init. One thing that doesn't make me think the new context is created from the store is that the child has unsaved parent changes such as changes to content and newly added. ... but just not the deleted ones.